# custom number format for a "named" textbox using Excel vba

Tags: vba

I have made an app that draws pipelines from a data table in profile. Part of the display includes "stationing" values that are a "custom" number format (e.g., 2571+36 from the value 25713.16) in textboxes. The textboxes are generated and deleted by my code so the system supplied name changes with each "refresh". I named the textboxes so that I can reference them programmatically, but have been unable to find the method to set the format. I've tried a bunch of approaches but none work...

    ws.Shapes.AddTextbox(msoTextOrientationHorizontal, Stat1X, StationingY, _
    60, 15).Name = "Stat1Text"

```
ws.Shapes("Stat1Text").DrawingObject.Text = Stat1AText

'ws.Shapes("Stat1Text").Text = Format(Number, "0000+00") 'tried
'ws.Shapes("Stat1Text").Value = Format("Stat1Text", "0000+00") 'tried

ws.Shapes("Stat1Text").Line.Visible = msoFalse
ws.Shapes("Stat1Text").TextEffect.FontBold = msoTrue
ws.Shapes("Stat1Text").TextEffect.FontSize = 10
```